# What has God not "desired" in Hebrews 10:8?

Tags: hebrews

"When he said above, "You have neither desired nor taken pleasure in sacrifices and offerings and burnt offerings and sin offerings"[these are offered under the Law]. Hebrews 10:8. ESV

What did God not desire?

A. That they make these sacrifices.

B. That they trust in these sacrifices.

C. That "the law" which required these sacrifices be retained, in favour of the "New" Hebrews 8:13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hebrews 10:8 means *exactly* what it says. The plain reading is clear. And, it has widespread support throughout scripture.

**PSALM 51: 16** *For thou hast no delight in sacrifice. If I were I to give a burnt offering, thou wouldst not be pleased.*

**ISAIAH 1:11** *”What to me is the multitude of your sacrifices? says the Lord;
I have had enough of burnt offerings of ram and the fat of fed beasts; I do not delight in the blood of bulls, or of lambs, or of he-goats*

The *difficulty* comes because the sacrificial ‘system’ is a foundation for some foundational, traditional doctrine. And, as well, they are pivotal for the rituals of atonement.(example Yom Kippur).

The  sacrifices that are in question are specifically the Sacrifices for ‘sin’ - we know this, or rather this is made clear in David’s response to his great ‘sin’, when he *didn’t* make any sacrifice to atone, but repented.

There were many sacrifices, and the other ones, example thanksgiving, first fruits, were *not*, and are *not* in question here in Hebrews 10. It is *only* the ‘sin’ sacrifices.

Theologians have apologetic arguments explaining these verses, or sometimes explaining them ‘away’. This answer is not interested in participating in this discussion, as you only asked “*What did God not desire*”  - and that is clear, *very* clear,  … sacrifices, *specifically* ‘sin’ sacrifices.

Answer (score 2):

The passage in Heb 10 cannot be subdivided.  The answer to the OP's question is found in  Heb 10:1-10 itself

> **1** For the law is only a shadow of the good things to come, not the realities themselves. It can never, by the same sacrifices offered
> year after year, make perfect those who draw near to worship. **2** If
> it could, would not the offerings have ceased? For the worshipers
> would have been cleansed once for all, and would no longer have felt
> the guilt of their sins.
>
> **3** Instead, those sacrifices are an annual reminder of sins, **4** because it is impossible for the blood of bulls and goats to take away
> sins. **5** Therefore, when Christ came into the world, He said:
> “Sacrifice and offering You did not desire, but a body You prepared
> for Me. **6** In burnt offerings and sin offerings You took no
> delight. **7** Then I said, ‘Here I am, it is written about Me in the
> scroll: I have come to do Your will, O God.’ ”
>
> **8** In the passage above He says, “Sacrifices and offerings, burnt offerings and sin offerings You did not desire, nor did You delight in
> them” (although they are offered according to the law). **9** Then He
> adds, “Here I am, I have come to do Your will.” He takes away the
> first to establish the second. **10** And by that will, we have been
> sanctified through the sacrifice of the body of Jesus Christ once for
> all.

Thus we observe the points made by the author of Hebrews:

- atonement for sin cannot be achieved by animal sacrifice - only Jesus' sacrifice can achieve that
- Thus, God did not desire animal sacrifice - it was only a reminder of Jesus the Messiah who was to come
- Thus the animal sacrifices were only a pointer to the real Messiah (V1)

**CONCLUSION**

God did not desire animal sacrifice as an atonement for sin - it was only specified in the law (Torah) as a pointer to what they represented - Jesus the Messiah who would be sacrificed for the atonement of all, and "once for all" (V10).

Answer (score 1):

What did God not desire?

<strike>A. That they make these sacrifices.</strike>
<strike>B. That they trust in these sacrifices.</strike>
<strike>C. That "the law" which required these sacrifices be retained.</strike>
 **D. Sacrifices without a Confession of sin**

**The prophet אָסָף Asaph (speaking for אֱֽלֹהִ֡ים יְהֹוָ֗ה. Elohim YHVH) sings the answer in Psalms 50.**

> [Tehillim | Psalms 50:14] 
> "Slaughter for Elohim a Confession and pay the Most High your vows." (זְבַ֣ח לֵאלֹהִ֣ים תּוֹדָ֑ה וְשַׁלֵּ֖ם לְעֶלְי֣וֹן נְדָרֶֽיךָ)

[Tehillim | Psalms 50:23]
**One who slaughters a confession sacrifice honors Me**, and [I will] prepare the way; I will show him the salvation of God." (זֹבֵ֥חַ תּוֹדָ֗ה יְכַ֫בְּדָ֥נְנִי וְשָׂ֥ם דֶּ֑רֶךְ אַ֜רְאֶ֗נּוּ בְּיֵ֣שַׁע אֱלֹהִֽים)

Answer (score 1):

What God did not desire was to continually have sacrifices made every year because they could never take away sin… It would be ongoing forever.  The only way to stop it was to have sin finally be taken away.  There's only one sacrifice that could take away the sin of the world once and for all.

Those sacrifices only reminded them of their sin, and their guilt.  They could never be free and move on in their relationship with God.  It just brought guilt instead of relief.

> it can never, by the same sacrifices that are continually offered every year, make perfect those who draw near.
> Otherwise, would they not have ceased to be offered, since the worshipers, having once been cleansed, would no longer have any consciousness of sins? <

It was all the animal sacrifices themselves He had no pleasure in because they could never take away sin.

> For it is impossible for the blood of bulls and goats to take away sins.<

> “Sacrifices and offerings you have not desired,
> but a body have you prepared for me;
> In burnt offerings and sin offerings
> you have taken no pleasure.<

It was only Christ body  that had been prepared by God himself for the one time sacrifice for all sin.  (behold the Lamb of God that takes away the sin of the world).  Christ blood alone could take away the sin of the world.  That is what he truly desired.

> Then I said, ‘Behold, I have come to do your will, O God,<

God was the one who offered the sacrifice for sin once and for all.  Christ's sacrifice of himself fulfilled the law in so many ways. He tasted to death for every man.

God's love has been manifested to the world through this one sacrifice of His son.  It's Christ blood they took away the sin of the world.  That takes away a guilty conscience and perfects forever one who wants to draw close to God now.  There is no separation between God and man. This is what God desired.  May he give us all the faith to believe it.

Answer (score 1):

The chapter opens with Hebrews 10:

> 1 The law is only a **shadow** of the good things that are coming—not the realities themselves. For this reason it can never, by the same **sacrifices** repeated endlessly year after year, make perfect those who draw near to worship.

It points out a major weakness of the law/sacrifices.
This same point continues:

> 4For it is impossible for the blood of bulls and goats to take away sins.
> 5Consequently, when **Christ** came into the world, he said,
> “Sacrifices and offerings you have not **desired**,
> but a body have you prepared for me;
> 6in burnt offerings and sin offerings
> you have taken no pleasure.

God had not desired sacrifices in the sense that it was only a shadow of the true reality which was Christ being the true sacrifice. Further,

> 9b He does away with the first [shadow sacrifice] in order to establish the second [Christ sacrifice].

What has God not "desired" in Hebrews 10:8?

I take the meaning "desired" in a relative sense here.
God desired a sincere sacrifice from the Israelites. More than that, God desired the sincere sacrifice from Christ.